# Are there any computer viruses that affect gpus?

Tags: gpgpu, gpu, virus

Recent developments in gpus (the past few generations) allow them to be programmed. Languages like Cuda, openCL, openACC are specific to this hardware. In addition, certain games allow programming shaders which function in the rendering of images in the graphics pipeline. Just as code intended for a cpu can cause unintended execution resulting a vulnerability, I wonder if a game or other code intended for a gpu can result in a vulnerability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The benefit a hacker would get from targeting the GPU is "free" computing power without having to deal with the energy cost. The only practical scenario here is crypto-miner viruses, see [this article](https://www.avg.com/en/signal/bitcoin-miner-malware) for example. I don't know details on how they operate, but the idea is to use the GPU to mine crypto-currencies in the background, since GPUs are much more efficient than CPUs at this. These viruses will cause substential energy consumption if unnoticed.

Regarding an application running on the GPU causing/using a vulnerability, the use-cases here are rather limited since security-relevant data usually is not processed on GPUs.
At most you could deliberately make the graphics driver crash and this way sabotage other programs from being properly executed.
There already are plenty security mechanisms prohibiting reading other processes' VRAM etc., but there always is [some way around](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/security/).